# How do I determine the jvm arguments to run a scala programs?

Tags: scala, jvm, classpath, jdi

TL;DR: What's the kosher way of launching Scala programs through JDI?

I want to use [JDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/overview-summary.html) to implement a debugger-of-sorts for Scala. In particular I want use a [LaunchingConnector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/connect/LaunchingConnector.html). And ideally I want the user to specify whether I should launch Scala 2.11 or 2.12.

I have Scala 2.11 installed on my system, and by running a Scala shell and looking in my process table I can establish that the following JVM command line options are sufficient to get the job done:

`environment.get("options").setValue("-Xmx256M -Xms32M -classpath /usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/hawtjni-runtime.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/jansi.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/jline.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-actors.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-compiler.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-library.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-parser-combinators.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-reflect.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-xml.jar:/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scalap.jar:scalacheck_2.11-1.14.1.jar:target/scala-2.11/classes/ -Dscala.home=/usr/share/scala-2.11 -Dscala.usejavacp=true -Denv.emacs=")`

For context, this is combined with `environment.get("main").setValue("scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner <my program> <arguments to my program>")` where (effectively but not literally) `val environment = com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().defaultConnector().defaultArguments()`.

Are all of the above necessary?

Is there some way I can launch a working Scala process using the JDI framework without hardcoding the above paths? Is there a way I can find out what paths to use for Scala 2.12?

Note that my classpath also includes a `scalacheck` jar file, which I manually downloaded. Can I programatically determine where sbt downloads library files to? Can I compute that part of the classpath too?